# Animate the first top stickyHeader in LazyColumn in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to animate only the top stickyheader when the user starts scrolling items in the header's group. The code below animates all headers when scrolling up or down.

One approach would be to get an index of the first visible header. However, the firstVisibleItemIndex represents the first item in the group, not the header. It seems that the compose LazyListState does not suppport getting stickyHeader index.

Is it possible to calcule the index based on the firstVisibleItemScrolOffset and the offset taken from the onPreScroll in NestedScrollConnection?

Perhaps there is another way to animate the top header only?

LazyColumn

```
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    val firstVisibleItemIndex = remember { derivedStateOf { listState.firstVisibleItemIndex } }
    val firstVisibleItemScrollOffset = remember { derivedStateOf { listState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset } }

LazyColumn(
        state = listState,
        modifier = modifier.nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
    ) {
        categories.forEachIndexed { index, category ->
            stickyHeader {
                SessionCard(
                    firstVisibleItemIndex = firstVisibleItemIndex.value,
                    firstVisibleItemScrollOffset = firstVisibleItemScrollOffset.value,
                    scale = scale.value,
                    index = index
                )
            }
            items(category.items) { text ->
                CategoryItem(text)
            }
        }
    }
```

Scale

```
val scale = remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
        object : NestedScrollConnection {
            override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                if (available.y < 0) {
                    scale.value = max(0.8f, scale.value - 0.01f)
                } else {
                    scale.value = min(1f, scale.value + 0.01f)
                }
                return Offset.Zero
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]